# If the row satisfies a certain condition, write the specific expression in the empty column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'action': ['visited', 'clicked', 'switched'], 
                   'target': ['pricing page', 'homepage', 'succeesed']
                   'type': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],})`
```

I have an empty "type" column in the dataframe. I want a text to be written if the row certain condition satisfies it. e.g;

`action=visited` and `target=pricing page` `get type=free`

[image]

Comment: [Please include your data in copyable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). If you've written code to solve your problem, please include it as well.

Comment: added an answer, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['action'].eq('visited') & df['target'].eq('pricing page'), 'type'] = 'free'
```

```
action  target  type
0   visited     pricing page    free
1   clicked     homepage    NaN
2   switched    succeesed   NaN
```